# Hit the "enter" instead "tab" or "ctrl+enter" in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I searched but didn't find it yet, how can I use "enter" instead of "tab" in visual studio for c++/c ?

No Ctrl+Enter, just enter for autocomplete

visual studio 2019

Comment: How would you enter the new line? Ctrl enter? Makes no sense for me

Comment: What exactly do you mean?  Do you want the code to format itself automatically when you press Enter?  Do you want to remap keys so that Enter works like Tab and Ctrl+Enter works like Enter?

Comment: @0___________ it seems you know only vs right? cause in clion and etc this is the way to autocomplete, and if you want a new line it makes sense you need ";" before so till you don't write it the ide assume you want to autocomplete, so before you vote negative, ask, it's free :)

Comment: @eglease yes, I want to remap the key, and instead (or additional) press tab to autocomplete, I want to press enter

Comment: *"clion and etc"* never heard about etc editor. Something new?

Comment: @0___________ I meant to all the JetBrains products, and I heard even visual studio for c#, so before you vote negative maybe you will be surprise by the new worlds outside the vs :)  https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/etc

Comment: You can't remap the Enter key in the default Visual Studio options but there might be some extensions that allow you to do this.

Comment: @eglease I use ReSharper but didn't see any option

Comment: there are a bunch of free extensions for VS2019.  Not sure which ones will do what you want but try https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mariasm.AltKeyboard&ssr=false#overview or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.HotKeys&ssr=false#qna

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, remapping certain keyboard keys in VisualStudio is [not allowed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/identifying-and-customizing-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#customize-a-keyboard-shortcut).

> You can't assign the following keys as part of a keyboard shortcut in Global:
>
> Enter, Tab, Caps Lock Print Scrn/Sys Rq, Scroll Lock, Pause/Break
> Insert, Home, End, Page Up, Page Down The Windows logo key, the
> Application key, any of the Arrow keys Num Lock, Delete, or Clear on
> the numeric keypad The Ctrl+Alt+Delete key combination

There are some 3rd party extensions that you can try but I haven't read anything about them being able to do what you want.

- [Hot Keys - Keyboard Shortcuts](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.HotKeys&ssr=false#qna)
- [AltKeyboardModes](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mariasm.AltKeyboard&ssr=false#overview)

If all else fails, you can try to [remap](https://www.howtogeek.com/710290/how-to-remap-any-key-or-shortcut-on-windows-10/) the keys in Windows but this will change them in all applications, not just VisualStudio.

[image]

[image]

Source: https://www.howtogeek.com/710290/how-to-remap-any-key-or-shortcut-on-windows-10/